# AjaxOptions.confirm does not pop up in ActionLink or BeginForm Submit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

New to this, so bear with me if I missed this somewhere in another answer.  I tried using AjaxOptions in Ajax.BeginForm and it did not pop up, so I switched to testing it in an ActionLink instead, and still can't get it to work.  For both the ajax.beginform and the ajax.actionlink it goes to the correct controller and carries on fine, but I get no confirmation message.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
K

From View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

@Ajax.ActionLink(
"Revoke Access to all Galleries Immediately", 
"ViewInvites", 
"Gallery", 
new AjaxOptions { 
    Confirm = "Are you sure you want to revoke access to all galleries? This cannot be undone.",
    HttpMethod = "Post"
}
)
```

Comment: Is it posting via Ajax to the controller? Do you have a reference to the jquery js library?

Comment: Your code as it is has no errors in it. Make sure you have a reference to the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min" javascript file on this page if you don't.

Comment: Yes I have references to the library. And isn't the <script> tag the reference "on this page?"  Thanks!  Still can't get it to work. in any page. ActionLink or using BeginForm!  Urgh....

Comment: And yes it is posting to the controller and it functions fine. the actions are performed and it posts back. Just NO Popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure the script tag is actually pointing to the correct script.  You may need to specify a relative path.

```
 <script src="../Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Firebug is helpful for discovering if this is the issue.