# Mvc delete object with ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a view with table of objects list. When I press "Delete" I want a confirmation popup (the borwser's default popup is fine) to show a message "Are you sure?" and confirmation will just delete the object from db and from the table int the view (without refreshing the page again).

In the table I have this code:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.LicenseID },
        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "onDeleteSuccess" },
        new { @class = "href", id = "delete", 
        onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');" })
```

My Delete action in the controller is this. along with a totally empty Delete view:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
{
    License license = unit.LicenseRepository.GetObjectById(id);
    if (license == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    unit.LicenseRepository.DeleteObject(license);

    unit.Save();

    return View(license);
}
```

I have few problems. Sometimes when I press "Delete" the object deleted succesfully.

Sometimes the page is redirecting to the empty Delete view page (if I'll delete the view page I'll get the error "The view 'Delete' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations").
Sometimes I'm getting the page HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found.

In both cases, when I'm returning to the table again I see that the object WAS deleted **succuessfully**.
So, why I'm getting those two pages? What's wrong?

Comment: What does `onDeleteSuccess` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AjaxOptions already have a Property for confirmation, try

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.LicenseID },
    new AjaxOptions { 
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        OnSuccess = "onDeleteSuccess",
        Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this?"
    },
    new { @class = "href", id = "delete"})
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.confirm(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: now it's just deleting the object, no popup message is shown before to confirm.

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253487/ajaxoptions-confirm-does-not-pop-up-in-actionlink-or-beginform-submit

Comment: alright, so I added the reference to unobtrusive-ajax and now it's good, but after deleting the object I need to manually refresh the page in order to see the changes, how can it delete from the table without refreshing the page again?

Comment: Find row <tr> by concrete selector, and then use remove() function. Before that you should set selector class to rows(during generating table)

Comment: @user2254436 you could delete the tr in the success event or you could put your whole table in a PartialView and return an updated version in your delete method... you should find plenty examples for this